# How to configure flink cluster memory managment

Tags: apache-flink, docker-swarm

I have a Flink cluster, and use it to run batch jobs. The problem is after of each the job, the taskmanager's memory used still busy.

The cluster is runnning in docker swarm, and have two machines with 250Gb of RAM.

My flink config is this:

```
by specifying the --host <hostname> parameter of the bin/jobmanager.sh executable.



by specifying the --host <hostname> parameter of the bin/jobmanager.sh executable.
# In high availability mode, if you use the bin/start-cluster.sh script and setup
# the conf/masters file, this will be taken care of automatically. Yarn/Mesos
# automatically configure the host name based on the hostname of the node where the
# JobManager runs.

jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager17

# The RPC port where the JobManager is reachable.

jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123


# The heap size for the JobManager JVM

jobmanager.heap.mb: 204800


# The heap size for the TaskManager JVM

taskmanager.heap.mb: 204800


# The number of task slots that each TaskManager offers. Each slot runs one parallel pipeline.

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 32

# Specify whether TaskManager memory should be allocated when starting up (true) or when
# memory is required in the memory manager (false)
# Important Note: For pure streaming setups, we highly recommend to set this value to `false`
# as the default state backends currently do not use the managed memory.

taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false

# The parallelism used for programs that did not specify and other parallelism.

parallelism.default: 1
```

The cluster works fine, but it is spending memory job at job and finally ends using swap and disk.

I hope that its a config problem, but if you need more details of docker, please tell me

Comment: How do you know "the taskmanager's memory used still busy."?

Comment: I check the machine memory using htop .

Comment: I check the machine memory using htop . Sorry , I was talking about the machine that ran the taskmanager container. It use some memory to run a job (obvius) but when the job ends, the memory still used (not obvius for me).
Thanks!

Comment: The TaskManager's JVM memory footprint will grow up to what's set by the `-Xmx` command line parameter when launching it. To really understand memory usage, you'll need to hook up something like YourKit to find out exactly what's still allocated and in use.